# A large if ... elif in python I want to improve in one line

Tags: python, if-statement, lambda

I have this long conditional statement

```
num = ['One', 'Five', 'Three', 'Four']
rating = []
for num in num:
    if  num == 'One':
        rating.append('1/5')
    elif num == 'Two':
        rating.append('2/5')
    elif num == 'Three':
        rating.append('3/5')
    elif num == 'Four':
        rating.append('4/5')
    elif num == 'Five':
        rating.append('5/5')
print(ratings)
```

and returns

`['1/5', '5/5', '3/5', '4/5']`

But I would like to improve this because I want this to be part of a line of code and this is too much to add.

I'm making some attempts with lambda functions but I have not made it yet. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: You could use a function, that does this. Define it somewhere and then use it in code.

Comment: Can you clarify what you are looking for? How do you expect this to fit into one line of code – do you want the entire code crammed into one line, or just create an abstraction that stores the logic elsewhere? Have you considered using a dictionary for the mapping from words to fractions?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replacements for switch statement in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60208/replacements-for-switch-statement-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a dictionary `pairs` to hold the corresponding values and then use a list comprehension to map it over nums.

```
pairs = {'One': '1/5', 'Two': '2/5', 'Three': '3/5', 'Four': '4/5', 'Five': '5/5'}

nums = ['One', 'Five', 'Three', 'Four']
ratings = [pairs[num] for num in nums if num in pairs]
```

Comment: Thanks sunnytown, this could be a solution. The list `num` is provided after a for loop that appends the result into the list `num`. So, I thought I can use an expression inside the loop in order to get every appended value in `num` and check if any of the conditions in the code above match and store the value "number/5" at once in the `num` list. I'll check this and the mapping proposed by @MauriceMeyer and see what happens. Thank you so much guys for your anwers.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a mapping dictionary, f-strings and a list comprehension:

```
nums = ['One', 'Five', 'Three', 'Four']
mapping = {'One': 1, 'Two': 2, 'Three': 3, 'Four': 4, 'Five': 5}

ratings = [f"{mapping.get(num)}/5" for num in nums if num in mapping]
print(ratings)
```

Out:

```
['1/5', '5/5', '3/5', '4/5']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `word2number` package:

```
pip install word2number
```

and do something like:

```py
from word2number as w2n

num = ['One', 'Five', 'Three', 'Four']
rating = [f'{w2n.word_to_numfor(i.lower())}/5' for i in num]
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this solution, I didn't know about the existence of the `word2number` package.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest and fastest method is the following:

```
num = ['One', 'Five', 'Three', 'Four']
ratings = ['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four', 'Five']
rating = [ str(ratings.index(_num)+1)+'/5' for _num in num ]
print(rating)
['1/5', '5/5', '3/5', '4/5']
```